# ASP .Net Page Can't Be Displayed Error

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2008, windows-7-x64

I am having the strangest issue. My website has been working perfectly in Visual Studio 2008 until I tried to work on the website in Visual Studio 2012. Having abandoned that idea, I am now back to Visual Studio 2008 with the following problem.

**Problem:**

Any page inside any folder displays a "Page can't be displayed" error or similar in all browsers (IE, Firefox, Chrome, Safari) **UNLESS** the page is a Default.aspx page. Break points do not load for any of the pages having problems, although debugging is enabled in Web.config. There are no errors in the event viewer.

**Possible reason for problem:**

- I tried working on the website in Visual Studio 2012. After it didn't recognize any of the imports, etc., I decided to just continue using Visual Studio 2008.
- I also deleted all of the files and folders in my %temp% directory

**What I've tried:**

- Create a new blank page in any folder to see if it will display; the page has the same error
- Comment out all code on an existing non-Default.aspx page; same problem
- Check the hosts file; nothing is active and other changes I've made had no effect
- Browse to another page from Default.aspx; same problem "Page can't be displayed"
- Checked for new AV, malware, etc. software recently installed; none installed
- Created a new site on the same machine to see if new site will have the same problem. New site works just fine.
- Cleared out the contents of C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files; no change

**Environment:**

- Visual Studio 2008 on Windows 7 x64. The backend is in VB .Net
- Running on the developer machine using ASP .Net Development Server

Any and all help is appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried restarting IIS? - You should also check your event log and also check IIS logs (turn on tracing).

Comment: I forgot to add that this is on the developer machine using ASP .Net Development Server. What event log can I check besides the Event Viewer? Thank you.

Comment: Try using administrative permission to open visual studio

Comment: @user2191496 Thank you for the suggestion but same problem

Comment: can you provide a sample solution and let us have a look?

Comment: @user2191496 I may do that if no one is able to provide any insight; it is a huge project with hundreds of files and tens of folders. Stripping it down will not be an easy task.

Comment: If it's too hard then try create a new website and do the same to see if it works

Comment: @user2191496 Good idea; I'm going to give that a shot ... though I dread to think about what happens if the other site works ...

Comment: @user2191496 I did create a new site on the dev machine, and it works just fine. It appears that only my old website is broken :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, I figured it out. Essentially, I was redirecting all but the Default.aspx pages to https (inside Global.asax). While this works on the production server that has valid certs, on the development machine, all one gets is the aforementioned behavior. Thank you all for the comments and suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same error.

Turning customErrors Off worked for me.

In web.config:

```
<customErrors mode="Off" defaultRedirect="ErrorPage.aspx" ...>
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case, Dropbox happened to be using the same port (49210). Fixed my issue by terminating the conflicting application. Alternately, change the port under the Project's properties.