# Response.Redirect Fails But then Works on Refresh IIS Express VS2013

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2013, iis-express

I have an ASP.NET project in Visual Studio 2013, running locally in IIExpress (Version 8.08418.0) for testing.

The main page (adminDefault.aspx) redirects user to Login.aspx to authenticate (which is done silently based on userID that was passed to adminDefault.aspx as a url variable). The login page sends it back to adminDefault.aspx upon successful authentication. Default then loads data into a Gridview.

The whole process takes about 15 seconds.

When I run this from Visual Studio 2013, I get an error "This page can't be displayed" in about 4 seconds. But if I manually hit refresh, after working for a bit, everything comes in fine.

[image: Showing Failure]

In my code, suspecting a timeout, I implicitly set this long enough to run through everything:

```
 if (!this.IsPostBack)
            {

                Session.Timeout = 120;  // seconds before timeout
                try
                {
                    // OnUser should have been set from Login.asp. If it is null, send to Login
                    MembershipUser onUser = Membership.GetUser();
                    if (onUser == null)
                    {
                        Response.Redirect("/login.aspx", true);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        String currentUserName = Membership.GetUser().UserName;
                        userRoles = Roles.GetRolesForUser(Membership.GetUser().UserName);
                    }
                }
```

Even if the Session.Timeout is being ignored, the default is 20 Seconds, so I would expect it to work anyway.

So: 
1) Why is the first run through failing? 
2) Is there a way I can prevent it? Failing that can I catch the page not found, and refresh automatically?

EDIT: This has something to do with the trip to Login.aspx and back. If I remove `Response.Redirect("/login.aspx", true);`
Then this works as expected. The problem is, I need the Login.aspx for validation. Anyone have any thoughts as to why the trip to Login and back is not working... and then does upon refresh?

When I try to run this in Chrome, I don't get as far. Chrome shows me this:

[image]

Hitting the **here** just cycles for a moment and comes back to the screen.

The Developer Tool on IE are not helpful (at least that i can see) in this case. When I run my project in the debugger, it launches a new IE session. Before I can turn on developer tools and press "Play" to record events, the session has given me "Cannot display the page" error. Of course I can hit "play" in the tools and then refresh, but of course everything runs then without error. The refresh makes everything run right. I need to discover why it fails before then.

**EDIT: This is the Login.aspx and Web.Security Code. I didn't write it, but it looks boilerplate:**

```
  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            string userName = "";
            bool authenticated = FormsAuthentication.Authenticate(ref userName);
            if (authenticated)
                {
                    FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(userName, false);
                }
     }
```

**And the Authentication code looks like this:**

```
        /// <summary>
    /// Validates a user based on the  session id found in the ReturnURL against credentials stored in the ASP.NET membership.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="userName">The user name.</param>
    /// <returns>true if the user name and password are valid; otherwise, false.</returns>
    public static bool Authenticate(ref string userName)
    {
        bool Authenticated = Authenticate(ref userName, GetSessionId());
        return Authenticated;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Redirects an authenticated user back to the originally requested URL or the default URL using the specified cookie path for the forms-authentication cookie.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="userName">The authenticated user name. </param>
    /// <param name="createPersistentCookie">true to create a durable cookie (one that is saved across browser sessions); otherwise, false. </param>
    /// <param name="strCookiePath">The cookie path for the forms-authentication ticket. </param>
    public static void RedirectFromLoginPage(string userName, bool createPersistentCookie, string strCookiePath)
    {
        System.Web.Security.FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(userName, false, strCookiePath);

        // Redirect back to request page.
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect(GetRedirectUrl());
    }
```

Comment: Have you checked this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18839409/asp-net-page-cant-be-displayed-error ??? Or this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18706173/how-to-fix-this-page-cant-be-displayed-error-in-asp-net ???

Comment: Yes. Neither applied. I am not using Https (first link solution) and in second case, it worked on localhost, but not in deployment, but my problem occurs on localhost.

Comment: Do you have the same problem when you deploy your solution?

Comment: It redirects to login for authorizing and fails within seconds. When I hit refresh, it comes back OK. I can't even figure out how to debug the issue. I tried increasing timeout, but no dice (and anyway, it fails prior to the default timeout hitting) To my knowledge, there is no way of trapping the timeout in debug.

Comment: Have not tried to deploy yet.

Comment: Try it, that can show you if there's a problem with your IISExpress. Also, do you have same problem with every browser? Is any other application on your computer using the same port that IISExpress is taking?

Comment: I'll try to do that, but I am working on the client's system, and I'm not sure how possible it is. I tried running it in Chrome and I don't get as far. I updated the question with a screenshot of what is happening there (Basically gets stuck at Login.aspx)

Comment: you can deploy on your computer, thus you can use your IIS server (not IISExpress). Hope it helps.

Comment: That doesn't work because I have to connect to their SQL-Server. But, I'll try to see if I can deploy it some way.

Comment: Examine the page requests in the Network tab of your browser's Developer Tools. Do you see anything odd, like the Login page repeatedly redirecting to itself?

Comment: have you redirected permanently from your code previously , if so clear the application pool and Temporary ASP.net files , Let me know if that works...

Comment: @MichaelLiu: I can get nothing from my developer tools (see edit in question -- image is pretty bad tho) Before I can get the developer tab up and recording events, the page has given me its cannot load error. When I active the recording events, and hit refresh, the page loads fine, so no error is seen.

Comment: @vishalsharma: I have cleared out the files created in C:\Users\<ME>\Documents\IISExpress several times. No joy. I am not sure how to clear the application pool in IIS Express. Can you point me to something that shows me how to do that?

Comment: If nothing works, try to change the way to authenticate to the recommended way in webforms like in this tutorial
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/301240/how-to-implement-forms-based-authentication-in-your-asp-net-applicatio
You can specify in the authentication mood to be Forms and specify the web page responsible for redirection, and change it in each subfolder by a web.config for that folder. 
More about the authentication element:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/1d3t3c61(v=vs.100).aspx

Just saying

Answer (score 1):

I think in your initial if statment you are assuming everyone is either logged in or not logged in.But users that are not logged in and people who visit that can also be anonymous (?). What you want to do is secure this admin.Default page and only allow authorized users. Currently your 2 conditions are send back the user to the login.aspx page (that they are currently on) if a user = null or get a role. 
Authentication is about knowing who the user is while authorization is all about access to resources .You want only authorized users to access that resource.

I would put the admin.Default.aspx,admin.Default.cs and admin.Default.designer.cs in their own folder called AdminSecure. Then after adding them inside that folder right click and add a Web.config file. In that Web.config what you need to do is deny anonymous users. So they automatically get redirected when they try and access that AdminDefault page.

//denies non logged in users ? == anonymous

```
<xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <system.web>
<authorization>
  <deny users="?"/>
</authorization>
    </system.web>
</configuration>


//this can allow particular users
<allow users="User1@mail.com"/>

//deny everyone but one user:
<allow users="User1@mail.com"/>
<deny users="*"/>
```

comment out your current code hope this helps.

Comment: This is an internal website. You are correct in that it should not allow anonymous users. The admin is actually called from an ERP system, which passes userID in. The Login.aspx will check that against an internal database to see if they are allowed. The symptom is that it appears to be passing the login, but the admin page fails before it loads. Refreshing it makes it load OK. It doesn't appear to be ping-ponging back and forth. It fails too quickly for that.

Comment: You should check your networking tab in chrome developer tools copy the the request and response headers and post them. I dont see a parameter where the userId is being passed inside the code you posted. Follow the path to where userID is being taken in as a parameter. Take good look at what happens after that.I would honestly need more info to help more.

Answer (score 1):

If Login.aspx redirects to adminDefault.aspx before it gets to persist a session to your browser, an infinite redirect loop will happen.

My clues:

1) As you already have a redirect loop - although not intentionally infinite - there is a risk of it becoming infinite under unhandled circumstances

2) you say that a timeout may be occurring, but the server side timeout is ignored: this leads me to think that this happens client side, and in fact could be your browser breaking the redirect loop as a safety measure

3) refreshing helps: this breaks the redirect loop after your session has been persisted client side

4) removing your redirection to adminDefault.aspx helps: this not only breaks the infinite loop, but removes the concept of the redirect loop

A few things you can to do test the redirect loop theory:

1) set a breakpoint on `Session.Timeout = 120;` and see where things go from there. You'll expect to get to `Response.Redirect("/login.aspx", true);` once only, but will probably see this line being hit continuously (once per redirection)

or

2) install [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/download/fiddler) and monitor your redirections.

If the above theory is correct, you have to ensure that Login.aspx gets to persist a session to the browser before redirecting to adminDefault.aspx. I.e., try and remove the redirection to adminDefault.aspx and see if you have gotten a session cookie after redirecting to Login.aspx - if not, you have your suspect. In short, Login.aspx is not done with it's work before you redirect back to adminDefault.aspx - so you have to let it. I can't be more specific without the Login.aspx code.

Comment: I have included code from the Login.aspx and Web.Security showing the login call to authenticate and redirect. (See Edit Above)  Does this help?

Comment: The logic looks fine, and a session cookie should be persisted (can you confirm?). Something must be going wrong in Authenticate(ref userName, GetSessionId()), so userName ends up staying empty. I don't see any credentials being passed either, which is worth some attention.

Comment: When UserName gets to FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage, it has a value. I'm not sure how to confirm a cookie gets created? But, the value being passed is actually FALSE so I doubt it is getting persisted.

Comment: In that case, what you're seeing is an infinite redirect loop due to wrong credentials or errors in the handling/processing of credentials. You're going to have to look at the credentials you're passing and follow them till the critical point where they are used to return a boolean result (inside Authenticate(ref userName, GetSessionId())).

Answer (score 0):

Based on your application circumstance in the comments, you cannot manage the authentication/authorization via web.config. And, `Membership` class is usually accessed if you have your custom provider, it's not the default way of accessing logged in users. So do either one of those:

1. Check the logged in user in your `if` statement the following way:

   ```
    if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
       Response.Redirect("/login.aspx", true);        
    }
    else
    {
       String currentUserName = Use User.Identity.Name; // accessing the logged in uer
       userRoles = Roles.GetRolesForUser(currentUserName); // not sure about this step, have you added your roles to web.Config? or from where you get them
    }
   ```
2. Depends on how your ERP integrates with your app (you should be using a custom provider), check where the users get authenticated. (ex. who is calling `Membership.ValidateUser(strUsername,strPassword)` . And make sure your login.aspx page is updating the session state.

Check [this page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f1kyba5e.aspx) for more information about implementing a custom provider

Comment: I think you are on to something. As I said, I inherited this code. It looks to me that the call out to a Login page is somewhat superflous here. But can you expand on this: "make sure your login.aspx page is updating the session state." It sets an auth cookie. (See new Edit above) is this what you mean?